# WPF WebBrowser HTML 5

Tags: jquery, .net, wpf, html, browser

I dragged a WPF WebBrowser Control into my Blend Project and then assigned the source to be a HTML5 Page. I wanted to utilize the LobsterPot HTML5 PivotViewer(url: LobsterPot HTML5 PivotViewer) into my WPF Application.

The Page Loads and then I get a notification at the top of the browser saying that active content has been blocked and when I click on Allow, the screen remains blank. Nothing is displayed on the Screen. Can anyone guide me and explain where I am going wrong...

```
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"    
    x:Class="CheckLobster.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Window"
    Width="640" Height="480" UseLayoutRounding="True" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowState="Maximized" Title="HTML 5 Pivot Viewer Sample"
    ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip">




    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="5" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="BackButton" Content="Back" Margin="5" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Press this button to navigate to the previous page" FontWeight="ExtraBold" MouseLeftButtonDown="BackButton_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <Button x:Name="NextButton" Content="Next" Margin="5" Cursor="Hand" ToolTip="Press this button to navigate to the next page." FontWeight="ExtraBold" MouseLeftButtonDown="NextButton_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="UriFieldTextBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="10,5,5,5" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" ToolTip="Enter the Web Address that you wanted to navigate to and press the Go Button" HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="300"/>
            <Button x:Name="GoButton" Content="Go" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5" FontWeight="ExtraBold" ToolTip="Press this button to navigate to the specified page." Cursor="Hand" MouseLeftButtonDown="GoButton_MouseLeftButtonDown"/>

        </StackPanel>

        <WebBrowser x:Name="MyWebBrowser" Margin="0" MinHeight="600"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Loaded="MyWebBrowser_Loaded" />


    </StackPanel>
</Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
        }

        private void BackButton_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            MyWebBrowser.GoBack();
        }

        private void GoButton_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            MyWebBrowser.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(MyWebBrowser_Navigating);
            MyWebBrowser.Navigated += new NavigatedEventHandler(MyWebBrowser_Navigated);
            string address = UriFieldTextBox.Text.ToString().Trim();
            MyWebBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(address,UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }

        private void NextButton_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            MyWebBrowser.GoForward();
        }

        private void MyWebBrowser_Loaded(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: Add event handler implementation here.
            MyWebBrowser.Navigating += new NavigatingCancelEventHandler(MyWebBrowser_Navigating);
            MyWebBrowser.Navigated+=new NavigatedEventHandler(MyWebBrowser_Navigated);
            Uri uri = new Uri("C:\\Users\\Manthravadi\\Desktop\\lobsterpothtml5pivotviewer-0.6.8\\examples\\PASS Summit 2011.html",UriKind.Absolute);
            MyWebBrowser.Source= uri;
        }



        void MyWebBrowser_Navigating(object sender,NavigatingCancelEventArgs args){
            MessageBox.Show("Page is Loading ...\n\nPlease wait");
        }

        void MyWebBrowser_Navigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs args){
            MessageBox.Show("Page has been Loaded ...!");
        }
```

Also, When I type an address such as "http://google.com" (without the quotes) into the UriFieldTextBox and press the Go Button, no page is loading, can someone explain where I am going wrong?

~ Harsha

Comment: It may sound to be a stupid question but did this HTML5 page work in your local IE browser?

Comment: You should not register event handlers in event handler - for example whenever you click Go new event handlers are registered for handling `Navigating` and `Navigated` events. Register them in constructor and only once.

Comment: didn't work in Internet Explorer.(I am using IE9) It only shows as Loading and never loads in IE9. In Chrome and Opera, a javascript alert is displayed an error saying "Error Loading CXML Collection".

But it works perfectly in Safari Browser...I am able to use the Zoom and stuff of the PivotViewer control in Safari.

Comment: okay..thx for the info @Karel Frajtak. Will do that immediately :)

Comment: fixed the Go Button Issue. Seems like it started working when I changed the Event from MouseLeftButtonDown to Click Event :s Also, initialized the event handlers in the constructors.

But I am still unable to run the PivotViewer HTML5 page. Is there any way to overcome the cannot load the .cxml file error? y isn't it loading? is there any way to find why the cxml file isn't being loaded in other browsers and why it is being loaded and the page works perfectly in Safari Web Browser alone...I need to apply this PivotViewer feature in my WPF Application. Any help would be appreciated :)